# html file issues deploying R shiny app to shinyapps.io

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinyapps

I wrote my first R Shiny app for a work project and am now attempting to deploy it to shinyapps.io. It works fine on its own when launched from RStudio and works fine when downloaded from my GitHub repository. You can download the repository here: https://github.com/UK-PHEG/PH1_Shiny_web_app/

The problem is that when I attempt to publish the app to shinyapps.io, I get the error:

```
✔ Deploying "PH1_shiny_app" using "server: shinyapps.io / username: uk-pheg"
Error in `inferAppPrimaryDoc()`:
! Failed to determine `appPrimaryDoc`.
✖ No files matching "\\.html?$".
```

So it looks like I need an HTML file. I did some research and found that I am supposed to specify my shinyApp() function as:

```
shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(primaryDoc = shiny::htmlTemplate("index.html")))
```

However, when I attempt this I get this error:

```
Warning in file(con, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'index.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

I cannot find any info online for what this html file needs to be, how to create it and where it needs to be placed in the directory structure. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show the `deployApp()` call you actually used to deploy your app? I suspect you may just have an issue with the path you provided

Comment: Previously I was using the "Publish" function from the app window. I've now just tried: rsconnect::deployApp("R_files"). Note that I previously had my folder containing the R files simply called "R", but the directory name needs to be at least three characters long so I just modified it now. My working directory is the Rproj directory which contains the "R_files" subdirectory.

Comment: I'm not an RStudio user, but I'm guessing the `Publish` button probably executes the deploy function in your current working directory. I would encourage you to add these details to your question, as they may help others in the future :-)

Comment: I agree I should have specified that, however, the rsconnect::deployApp() function generates the same result. When I try your answer, I just get an error that the directory does not exist. This is because the working directory is in fact the Rproj directory. When I specify rsconnect::deployApp('R_files/') I get the original error message. Is there a problem with the way I have built my directory structure?

Comment: It most likely is related to the used naming scheme and directory structure, not sure how/why `rsconnect` would pick up `./R/ph1_shiny_app.R` instead of regular `./app.R` . Perhaps try to align to what you'd get though a new Shiny project template in RStudio or https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/latest/shinyapptemplate ?

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I wasn't aware the app had to be specifically named app.R. The upload worked! However, when I launch the app online I get error: "An error has occurred The application failed to start. exit status 1". Do all files including data need to be contained in the specified directory?

Comment: Data files should be somewhere under the app root directory, if you have still the same directory structure as in your Github repo, I'm afraid it will not work as data files are outside of app's root.  You can download deployed app bundle from https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/dashboard to see what was included  how it's all organized.

Comment: Great thanks. I think I now have everything I need to get this working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error implies that the `deployApp()` function has failed to find the primary document of your Shiny application, e.g. an `app.R` file, or corresponding `ui.R` and `server.R` files.

Chances are you are simply providing the root directory of your project files, but not the root directory of the *Shiny project* itself. The path you should specify is the directory that contains the `app.R` file.

e.g. with the following directory structure

```
.
└── your-project/
    └── R/
        └── app.R
```

you should call `deployApp('your-project/R/')`.